# How can I disable the Hellobar through JS code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The hellobar is an email collector. It shows a popup where users can enter their email to join an email list. The JS code is loaded from a 3rd party hellobar domain.

In the past we could set a certain magic cookie via PHP code like "DontShowHB" and if this cookies was found then there was no popup. This method does not exist anymore. This allowed us to disable the hellobar for certain visitors that the server could identify.

```
if (certain situation met) then
   set disable hellobar cookie => hellobar would not show
else 
   show the hellobar
```

**So my question is:** if we want to disable the hellobar again via code. How can we do this?

(can we destroy the hellobar object via JS or can we set a certain variable to disable the hellobar? The long and the short is: how can we create a situation where the hellobar does not get triggered and stays silent)

This is the Hellobar code script (sorry it is minified by default): https://my.hellobar.com/modules-v26.js

This is the JS code that calls this script

```
    window.hellobarSiteSettings = window.hellobarSiteSettings || {
    "preview_is_active": false,
    "capabilities": {
        "autofills": false,
        "geolocation_injection": false,
        "external_tracking": false
    },
    "site_id": 123,
    "site_url": "https://example.com",
    "pro_secret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "site_timezone": "+01:00",
    "hellobar_container_css": "#CODE REMOVED FOR EASY READING#"
};
var bootstrap = function(t) {
    var e = document,
        a = e.head || e.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    script = e.createElement("script"), script.async = 1, script.src = t, a.appendChild(script)
};
bootstrap("https://my.hellobar.com/modules-v26.js");
```

Help appreciated

Comment: how is this script getting injected in your code? is it a browser extension?

Comment: If you're going to provide a code link, use non-minified code. That code is unreadable.

Comment: There's a support website: https://support.hellobar.com/

Comment: @ShubhamGupta See my question update. Barmar Sorry can un-minify external code there is a beautifier here https://beautifier.io/ and we know where to find support. This question is not listed. And thus not answered. I am hoping a Javascript Expert can answer the questions or give us a nudge in the right direction. This will help many users.

Comment: Could I use `jQuery("script[src='https://my.hellobar.com/modules-v26.js']").remove();` or is there a more sophisticated way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved as follows and added this code to footer.

Because we run a multsite we needed array of HB codes. Lookup code. Lookup cookie.

**If:** both found then go through JS code to load the Hellobar Javascript

**Else**: do not

Tip! Check the caching of the template code where this is placed

```
<?php

    /**  CUSTOM CODE - HELLOBAR **/
    $hellobardomains = array(
        "example.com" => "CODEHERE",
    );
    $_hellobarcode = $hellobardomains[$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']];

   /* Logic here on server side PHP to set Cookie "HBDismissed" to true */


?>

/* Logic here on client side JS to set Cookie "HBDismissed" to true */

var HBCode = "<?php echo $_hellobarcode; echo $_domain;?>";
var HBLoad = (YourFunctiontoGetCookies.get("HBDismissed") == null);

if (HBCode.length > 0 && HBLoad) {
    t = "//my.hellobar.com/"+HBCode+".js";
    var e = document, a = e.head || e.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    script = e.createElement("script"), script.async = 1, script.src = t, a.appendChild(script)
};
```

NB. If the Hellobar team reads this. A better solution would be either

1. a cookie filter function in your GUI to read this cookie
2. a global variable we can set to true/false that is respected by the JS module